# how can use Application_BeginRequest event in c# window application

Tags: c#, url, browser

I have developed c# windows application and I want to use ASP.NET code like
`Application_BeginRequest` event in window application for trace URL.

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose you will need to host the asp.net web service outside of the IIS, because you have windows application.
That is possible by making your windows application also self hosting using OWIN/Kataina. For more information [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana)